# ImageLoader show image slowly in second activity

Tags: image, android-listview, thumbnails, universal-image-loader, android-assets

I have two activies that use UIL. 
My general configuration application of UIL is:

```
public static void configureDefaultImageLoader(Context context) {
    DisplayImageOptions thumbOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error_red_24dp)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(90))
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(thumbOptions)
            .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .threadPoolSize(5)
            .build();

    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}
```

Either activies have a custom adapter, that initialize UIL in constructor.
In my first activity the loading is fast, and anything work. The code's adapter is:

```
 private ImageLoader imageLoader;


public ListViewAdapter(Context context)
{
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

}
```

and in getView method:

```
    if(thumbName != null ) {

        imageLoader.displayImage("assets://coralsImages/" + thumbName, viewHolder.imageView);
    }
```

The code's adapter in second activity is ugual, but loading is more slowly and difficult.How can resolve this problem?